# Es6 - sorting by boolean property and then in descending order

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects

```
 myArray= [{"FName":"",
            "LastName":"",
            "data" :[{
                      active:true,
                      times: 50
         },{
                      active: false,
                      times:450
         }

         ]}]

 myArray.map(x => x.data = x.data.sort((y,z) => y.times > z.times))
```

But how do I sort so that Initially I ihave the data whose active field is TRUE, and then sort by Times ?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you read up on how `sort` works on JS arrays? See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1):

The [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)  compareFunction(a, b) function should return a number:

- Negative number - **a** should come before **b**.
- 0 - **a** and **b** have the same priority.
- Positive number - **b** should come before **a**.

In your case the logic is find the order by `active`, and if both have the same `active` value, check the `times`. We can use simple subtraction, since booleans are treated as numbers (0 | 1):

```
z.active - y.active || z.times - y.times
```

**Notes:**

1. Since you are using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), return clones of the objects, and arrays to prevent changes to the originals. If you want to change the original, use [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead. I clone the objects and arrays using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).
2. In sort, if two items have the same value (comparator result 0), the order is not guaranteed, and depends on the browser's implementation.

**Example:**

```js
const myArray = [{"FName":"","LastName":"","data":[{"active":true,"times":50},{"active":false,"times":450},{"active":false,"times":50},{"active":true,"times":450}]}]

const result = myArray.map(x => ({
  ...x,
  data: [...x.data].sort((y,z) => z.active - y.active || z.times - y.times)
}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

use a custom sorter

```
var sorter = function(a, b) {
   if (a.active || b.active) {
       return 1
   }
   return 0
}

var array = [{active: false, name: 'one'},
 {active: true, name: 'two'},
 {active: true, name: 'three'},
 {active: false, name: 'four'}]
array.sort(sorter).map((obj) => {console.log(obj)})
```

Works :D

Answer (score -1):

You can first sort the data array on times. Then add one more sort function on data to sort by active flag;

```js
myArray= [
  {
    "FName": "",
    "LastName": "",
    "data": [
      {
        "active": true,
        "times": 50
      },
      {
        "active": false,
        "times": 450
      },
      {
        "active": true,
        "times": 20
      },
      {
        "active": true,
        "times": 350
      },
      {
        "active": true,
        "times": 200
      },
      {
        "active": false,
        "times": 100
      }
    ]
  }
]

myArray.map(x => {
  x.data = x.data.sort((y,z) => y.times > z.times).sort((y,z) => y.active < z.active);
});

console.log(myArray)
```